# MySQL - How do I include a column that has the difference of 2 rows from the result of a nested select?

Tags: mysql, left-join

**Setup:**
I have two tables that are similar to the following:

```
Table: tickets
+------+------+------------+----------+----------+--------+-----+--+
| Site | Rack | Start Date | End Date | iv_begin | iv_end | ... |  |
+------+------+------------+----------+----------+--------+-----+--+
| 1    | 1    | 2016       | 2017     | 900      | 1000   | ... |  |
| 1    | 1    | 2016       | 2017     | 800      | 900    | ... |  |
| 1    | 1    | 2016       | 2017     | 700      | 800    | ... |  |
| 1    | 1    | 2016       | 2017     | 600      | 650    | ... |  |
+------+------+------------+----------+----------+--------+-----+--+

Table: sites
+----+----------+
| ID | sitename |
+----+----------+
| 1  | Atlanta  |
| 2  | Boston   |
+----+----------+
```

First, I am having to use a nested select to get a result table to then query from.  For example:

```
SELECT Q1.rownum, Q1.name AS "Site", Q1.rack, Q1.iv_begin, Q1.iv_end
FROM    
  (
  SELECT (@cnt := @cnt + 1) AS rownum, 
  S1.name, T1.rack, T1.batch_start, T1.batch_end, 
  T1.batch, T1.iv_begin, T1.iv_end      
  FROM tickets T1       
  LEFT JOIN sites S1 ON T1.Site = S1.ID         
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @cnt := 0) AS dummy1       
  WHERE T1.rack = 1         
  ORDER BY 
   T1.batch DESC, 
   T1.iv_begin DESC, 
   T1.iv_end DESC       
   LIMIT 200
  ) 
  AS Q1
```

To get a result similar to this:

```
+--------+---------+------+----------+--------+
| rownum |  Site   | Rack | iv_begin | iv_end |
+--------+---------+------+----------+--------+
|      1 | Atlanta |    1 |      900 |   1000 |
|      2 | Atlanta |    1 |      800 |    900 |
|      3 | Atlanta |    1 |      700 |    800 |
|      4 | Atlanta |    1 |      600 |    650 |
+--------+---------+------+----------+--------+
```

**Question:**
How would I add a column to the final results that is the difference of 2 rows values?  For example, I'm trying to get the column "iv_diff" = (rownum[N] iv_begin) - (rownum[N+1] iv_end).  The iv_end value should match the iv_begin value of the preceding row.  The iv_diff column is to find out if that's not the case, and if so, what the difference is.

So the resultant table should look like this:

```
+--------+---------+------+----------+--------+---------+
| rownum |  Site   | Rack | iv_begin | iv_end | iv_diff |
+--------+---------+------+----------+--------+---------+
|      1 | Atlanta |    1 |      900 |   1000 |       0 |
|      2 | Atlanta |    1 |      800 |    900 |       0 |
|      3 | Atlanta |    1 |      700 |    800 |       0 |
|      4 | Atlanta |    1 |      600 |    650 |      50 |
+--------+---------+------+----------+--------+---------+
```

I've tried copy/pasting the same select so that I also have a result Q2, and then tried to LEFT JOIN Q1 and Q2...(ON Q1.rownum = Q2.rownum+1)...but I can't seem to get the iv_diff column to return the results I need (sometimes it gives a cumulative sum, which isn't right).

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use another user variable to hold the value from the previous line.

```
SELECT Q1.rownum, Q1.name AS "Site", Q1.rack, Q1.iv_begin, Q1.iv_end, Q1.iv_diff
FROM    
  (
  SELECT (@cnt := @cnt + 1) AS rownum, 
      S1.name, T1.rack, T1.batch_start, T1.batch_end, 
      T1.batch, T1.iv_begin, T1.iv_end, 
        IF(@prev_begin IS NULL, 0, T1.iv_end - @prev_begin) AS iv_diff, @prev_begin := T1.iv_begin
  FROM tickets T1       
  LEFT JOIN sites S1 ON T1.Site = S1.ID         
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @cnt := 0, @prev_begin := NULL) AS dummy1       
  WHERE T1.rack = 1         
  ORDER BY 
   T1.batch DESC, 
   T1.iv_begin DESC, 
   T1.iv_end DESC       
   LIMIT 200
  ) 
  AS Q1
```

Answer (score 1):

If your query already produce this:

```
+--------+---------+------+----------+--------+
| rownum |  Site   | Rack | iv_begin | iv_end |
+--------+---------+------+----------+--------+
|      1 | Atlanta |    1 |      900 |   1000 |
|      2 | Atlanta |    1 |      800 |    900 |
|      3 | Atlanta |    1 |      700 |    800 |
|      4 | Atlanta |    1 |      600 |    650 |
+--------+---------+------+----------+--------+
```

Then just add a subquery.

```
 SELECT   T1.*, COALESCE(T1.iv_begin - T2.iv_begin, 0) as iv_diff 
 FROM ( YourQuery ) as T1
 LEFT JOIN ( YourQuery ) as T2
    ON T1.rownum = T2.rownum - 1
```

But notice T1 and T2 need to use differente `@cnt`  variables to create `rownum`

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I did try to COALESCE approach as well, but I never got it to work.

Comment: is weird because is same function as `IF` function from Barmar answer. Anyway Barmar answer is much better. But if you want see COALESCE [samples](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp)